# How to patch SUDS python

Tags: python, soap

I am trying to place SOAP calls to Cisco AXL interface using Python with SUDS. similar to "[Valid SOAP call not working in Python SUDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578802/valid-soap-call-not-working-in-python-suds.)".
I followed the Answer too. But, still I am getting the same error `Item not valid`

Since I had SUDS4.1, I did not apply any patch on SUDS. I am thinking may be the patch will resolve my problem. So I want to know what patch should I apply and how to I apply the patch.